# In Powerquery: Is it possible to use a columname and its content in form of wildcards to find strings in other column?

Tags: string, find, powerquery, wildcard

In PowerQuery I'd like to find the strings (names) I have in one column (called `Vorname`) in another column (called `Verwendungszweck 1`) containing the strings anywhere.

So I think I have to use wildcards or the like.

```
    #"Hinzugefügte benutzerdefinierte Spalte2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Neu angeordnete Spalten2", "Passende Gutschriften", each List.AnyTrue([Vorname], [Verwendung 1]))
in
    #"Hinzugefügte benutzerdefinierte Spalte2"
```

Please tell me the syntax I have to use. Sorry for the German :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `List.Contains`

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Neu angeordnete Spalten2", "Passende Gutschriften", each List.Contains(#"Neu angeordnete Spalten2"[Verwendungszweck 1],[Vorname]))
```

If you want partial matches included:

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Neu angeordnete Spalten2", "Passende Gutschriften", each List.Contains(#"Neu angeordnete Spalten2"[Verwendungszweck 1],[Vorname], (MyList as text, MyName as text)=>Text.Contains(MyList,MyName)))
```

### EDIT

Here's an example PBIX file which demonstrates, checking for the existence of each `Vorname` value in any row of column `Verwendungszweck 1`

https://pwrbi.com/so_55375811/

### EDIT 2:

Same example in Excel format:

https://excel.solutions/so_55375811/

Comment: [Edit] your question to include some sample data, and expected outcome.

Comment: tnx Olly, do I have to edit the MyList and MyName from your code? Because I don't get any matches, only false and error(null can't be used). Does your code really find text from any one text in column(Vorname) anywhere in each entry of column(Verwendungszweck 1)? That is to say to itinerate through each entry of column(Verwendungszweck 1) with each and every entry of column(Vorname)

Comment: It does exactly that. See worked example PBIX file in my edit, to demonstrate.

Comment: Dear Olly, sorry for the fuss, but I'm working with Excel16, and I don't have Power BI :( I can't open the PBIX...(no admin rights eather). Clarifing example here too: e.g. [Vorname] contains text "Miro", different row [Verwendung 1] contains "jova and Miro2019", new column needs to state true here. Hope you are still willing to help a noob out here ;)

Comment: Edited answer to include an example Excel file, to show how it's working.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, "Verwendungszweck 1" column contains text values, "Vorname" column contains substrings, and **for each row** you want to find if the text value from "Verwendungszweck 1" Column contains the substring from "Vorname" column. If so, formula should be like this:

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Neu angeordnete Spalten2", "Passende Gutschriften",
                   each Text.Contains([Verwendungszweck 1], [Vorname]))
```